# the margin value of a Canvas remains 0 after using DeltaManipulation to tansform it - window phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

```
void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        //(0/-897)(0/-135)
        // Move the rectangle.

        Thickness mapmar = MapCont.Margin;

        Current.Text = mapmar.Left+"_"+mapmar.Top;

        if (marginThickness.Left < 0)
        {
            MapCont.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
        }

        move.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        move.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;



    }
```

The idea is that the Canvas is Really big for the view so i use the DeltaMaipulation to allow the user to scroll around it, i need to keep track of the margins to force some clipping

i tried printing the values of the margins (textfield) it's 0 0 no matter what

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The ManipulationDelta Doesn't use the Margin property to position the elements

alternative code:-
use the TranslateTransform Object

```
private TranslateTransform move = new TranslateTransform();
```

use the X and Y attributes to do the clipping or any related thing

```
if (move.X < 0)
        {
            move.X = 0;
        }
```